# Get Visual Studio settings through C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sdk

I have been browsing the internet for an hour already but I couldn't find any documentation regarding retrieving Visual Studio Settings (such as TFS url, Proxy Url, etc.) through C# in a **standalone** application.
I suppose I should use the Visual Studio SDK.
Any code snippet would be appreciated!

Comment: Aren't the settings files simply XML in the user's appropriate AppData directory? =)

Comment: Hmm, might be.. let me check :)

Comment: Oups. In the Documents folder, actually. Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Settings

Comment: Allright. That's a solution. So now, is there a VS SDK function call that reads the settings from this file or I have to parse it by myself?

Comment: I'd suggest parsing it by yourself, but there might be an SDK call available. I haven't looked through it myself. =)

Comment: I found those settings in the Registry as well.

Comment: I don't know if it will good enough for your need, but Visual automation give access to the profile. I don't know to what extent, but this could be a start : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprofiledatamanager.aspx